# Implicitly import specific Swift module

Tags: swift

I use a third party Swift framework in my Swift app very often and would like to use it without having to write `import ModuleName` in every single Swift file over and over again.

Is there a way to specify default imports like it was possible in Objective-C using a `.pch` file?

I already checked Xcode build settings and `swiftc` flags but none of them offers this functionality.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually there's a very easy workaround I could have thought about earlier…

Simply add the following to your app project's Objective-C bridging header:

```
@import ModuleName;
```

Swift will pick it up too! No need for `import ModuleName` in every Swift file where you intend to use the module.

Comment: won't work if the target being created is a Swift framework dependent on other modules as bridging headers are not permitted

Comment: @MaxMacLeod yep this only works for app targets. For frameworks there doesn't seem to be any functionality or workaround to achieve the same result. But I got used to it :)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no Swift analogue for Objective-C `.pch` files.

One could ostensibly reduce the number of import statements by creating an umbrella target framework that includes a number of other modules, but there's no way to avoid explicit imports of dependent modules outright.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mattt. I guess you're correct that there is no standard way to do that in Swift. But I found a way to achieve the same result by just using `@import` in ObjC's bridging header!

Comment: Swift has `.swiftmodule` files which are importable when one provides its dirname as the value fo the `-I` argument of `swiftc`. [SWM (Swift Modules)](http://github.com/jankuca/swm) can help a lot with these.