# How to import existing Objective C PCH file in Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pch

I have declared URLs etc in PCH file in objective C project. I am also using swift in same project but not able to get those URLs declared in PCH file. I tried by importing PCH file in bridging header but values are not showing in swift View controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get `.PCH` values from Swift.

For more information refer this question : [Why .pch file not available in Swift ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26408612/2922788)