# My Framework's PCH file isn't applied after adding a Swift file to the project, Podfile

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, pch

I have a Workspace with 2 projects, where one is a "common" project with code to share between projects and targets and the other is my main IOS app.
So, I have a podspec for it, and use that in my "main" projects podfile. This has worked well for years.

Now, my "common" project has only contained objective-c files, and both it and my main project have PCH files where I have common imports.

I am about to migrate to Swift (long overdue) so, I tried to just add a Test.swift to my common project.

When I tried to do pod install, I got this error:

> The Swift pod X depends upon `JSONModel`, which do not define modules.
> To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary
> to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may
> set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify
> `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

So, I did that, but what happens now is that the project doesn't compile. More specifically, the #import's in my PCH files don't seem to be applied for some reason. PCH extract:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import "MyConstants.h"
#endif
```

Error example:

> projects/iphone/Pods/Headers/Public/MyCommons/Status.h:47:30: Unknown
> type name 'Role'

, which is an enum, defined in MyConstants.h

The weird thing is that I put a #warning inside the #ifdef and it IS logged when every file is compiled, including Status.h that I mention above.

This is definitely not my expertise, so if someone knows more than me, pointers are appreciated. Optimally, I would like to be able to mix Swift and Objective-C in my commons module but still have the PCH file applied to the Objective-C files, until I have moved on 100%.

Comment: Tu call swift from Objective-C you need to include the project-Swift.h file in Objective-C code that use swift. You must also create a bridging header to enable swift to know about Objective-C classes.

Comment: Yes that is true and I know that. This question is about something non-related, it's how my PCH file is no longer applied to my ojective-c file.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672419/how-to-import-existing-objective-c-pch-file-in-swift-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408612/implicitly-import-specific-swift-module) ?

Comment: Those are related to Swift. As I just mentioned, I am talking about applying PCH to Objective-C files.